# Client-side URL redirect error for $route.hash

Tags: vue.js, security, vue-router, websecurity

GitHub code scanning started to complain about my old Vue code that there is an security alert. I do understand its purpose - an attacker can create a malicious URI that will do something nasty.

> Client-side URL redirection based on unvalidated user input may cause
> redirection to malicious web sites. CWE-79  CWE-116  CWE-601

It dislikes the following code which is a workaround to scroll down to the specified anchor in Vue:

```
  mounted() {
    const { hash } = this.$route;
    if (this.$route.hash) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        window.location.href = hash;
      }, 1000);
    }
  },
```

The first of all - is it really unvalidated? It is processed by Vue-router. The second - is there anything I can do with this alert? I am considering to ignore it. Bad idea?

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to jump to an anchor, the workaround is unnecessary. Configuring Vue Router's [scroll behavior](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html) to automatically scroll to the `hash` element would also resolve the GitHub warning:

```js
// router.js
const router = new VueRouter({
  //...
  scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
    if (savedPosition) {
      return savedPosition
    }
    if (to.hash) {
      return {
        selector: to.hash,
        behavior: 'smooth'
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/scroll-to-hash-in-vue-router-veofl?file=/src/router.js:313-520)

Comment: Hi, your demo works fine but not in my project. I have already tried this approach in past: https://github.com/literakl/mezinamiridici/blob/master/spa/src/router.js. The only workaround to make it work was that mounted hack.